# Is it clear to store partial view names in view model properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC project I have the situation where I need to dynamically change the behavior of how particular partial views will be rendered. I know that one option would be to do the decision inside parent view (by some sort of conditionals) and then render the parent partial view.

However I do not like the logic within views at all. Also this is not extensible for the future changes (e.g. adding new partial view would also require changes within parent view). So that I have end up with view models that contains properties defining names of partial views to render. So that razor code then looks like this:

```
@Html.Partial(Model.ChildViewName, Model.Child);
```

All the decision logic is done in the backend code in factory that produces the view models. This is pretty flexible and extensible. However I do not like the coupling between models and views as I believes that view model should be just and envelope for the data and view should only display them. So that I am wondering if there is better or more elegant way how to handle this problem.

Comment: What is the condition that the partial view is based on - is it based on a value of a property in your model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, basically it is information that is coming from the outside of MVC application (e.g. configuration file, external Web API service etc.). I usually write a factory that talks to this external data sources and creates and then populates the view model with that data.

Comment: A view model is supposed to represent what you need to display/edit in a view so I don't see having a property that describes the child view as a problem. However, you could always use `@Html.Action()` rather than `Html.Partial()` so that you call a `[ChildActionOnly]` method that returns the appropriate partial view so that the logic is all done in the controller.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to use `@Html.Action()`. However, passing complex model is quite complicated in that case.

Comment: Why would you need to pass the whole model?

Comment: Just have a look to code sample in my question. I usually need to pass a Model.Child to the partial view and that is complex object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159646/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ondra-netocny).